After closing the popup window main window is not focusing its continuously revolving, any solution for this
After closing the popup window main window is not focusing and it is continuously revolving, any solution for this.
Used wait 10 min but still continuously revolving and main window not focusing. tried window handle method but not success.

Add the code snippet and the DOM you are working with and describe which part you are facing the problem with.
